# How can I place the "Add New Post" contents on a custom page?

Tags: admin

I created an alternative to the default WordPress Admin panel for my writers to use as I wanted more flexibility (in design) and a simpler interface. I've been successful thus far but I can't seem to figure out how to take the "Add New Post" page from the default wp-admin to my custom page.

What I mean is, I would like to take all of this
[image]

and put it on my own page. I've looked over the post-new.php and edit.php scripts but have had no luck.

Is this even possible?

I have just discovered the wp_editor function...but is it possible to add all the other things from the "Add New Post" page as well (such as the featured image, tags, categories sections, etc...)?

Comment: Do you want it in front-end or back-end (in `/wp-admin`)?

Comment: I believe it would be considered back-end as I'm essentially creating a second wp-admin.

Comment: Please can you explain. Is this a new custom post type or the default edit, create post screen with changes on design? The String is from the init of a post type and it is possible to change via translation or hook.

Comment: It's a create post screen. What I'm trying to do is create a new "create post" screen that's identitcal to the default one in wp-admin, just have it on a different page.

Comment: You might get some tips from https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso. It's an open-source project that rebuilt the entire admin section of WP.